# QtCharts - How to set fixed Y axis scale?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I am using Qt Framework (C++) to create a bar chart of percentages. How to make make the Y-axis that shows percentages always remain at 100% even if none of the values are near 100%?

[In this picture, the maximum percentage of an instance is only 60 and hence the Y-axis shows only until 60. It does not show until 100.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE0e8.png)

[In this picture, the maximum percentage is only 80 and so the Y-axis shows only until 80.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZORW.png)

How to make the chart show a scale of 100 in the Y-axis all the time?

Comment: You need to post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was setting the range as (100,100) instead of (0,100). The correct code is:
`axisY->setRange(0,100);`

I also added `axisY->applyNiceNumbers();` and `agamAxisY->setTickCount(10);` so that the graph is beautifully incremented by 10 percentage points from 0-100.

Hope this helps someone out there.